# Is SignedXml KeyInfoX509Data reusable and thread safe?

Tags: .net, xml, cryptography

I am creating SignedXml documents, part of this process is initializing the KeyInfoX509Data from the certificate:

```
void Sign(
    System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml signedXml,
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    ...
    var keyInfo = new KeyInfoX509Data(cert, X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot);
    signedXml.KeyInfo.AddClause(keyInfo);
    ...
}
```

This method is taking a long time, and I narrowed it down to the "newKeyInfoX509Data()" line.  My guess is it's doing something with the keychain, it just sits there idle for 10-15 seconds.

If I'm re-using the certificate to sign multiple XMLs, I think I should be able to create a single KeyInfoX509Data and reuse it for all the signed XML documents, even across multiple threads.

Does the SignedXml change any state of the KeyInfoX509Data class that would make it unsafe to re-use, either consecutively or simultaneously across threads?

Comment: The [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.keyinfox509data(v=vs.110).aspx) specifically states at the bottom of the page that `KeyInfoX509Data` instances aren't "guaranteed to be thread safe." So I would suggest that you try it for yourself and see what happens. If it turns out not to be thread safe, then maybe us a `BackgroundWorker` or `Task`.

Comment: I can see that it has public methods AddCertificate, AddSubjectKeyId, AddSubjectName, etc. which is obviously non-threadsafe.  But as long as SignedXml treats it as readonly, it should be fine.  Just like a List<T> is threadsafe if you only read from it, and you only have issues if other threads try to read/modify it while it is undergoing modifications.

Comment: And if it's safe to re-use consecutively, but not concurrently, I can always lock the KeyInfoX509Data.